# What to use to manage storage and snapshot/backups for KVM host?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, zfs

I have built a KVM host, on which I will run 10-15 vm's. I am still thinking what is the most efficient and easiest way to manage its storage (5 disk with 3TB's) and the backups of the machines. For now:

- I have created raidz2 from the 5 disks
- Still debating if I need zfs. Snapshotting and restoring is easier with it, but creating dataset and attach it as vm disk seems to be hard.

Comment: "Best" is opinion based - please provide atleast some criteria.

Comment: @Panki easy to manage and efficient. There are no requirements

Answer (score 0):

Is your KVM host using libvirt to manage the virtual machines? If so, you could use this utility to create consistent virtual machine backups to your backup storage:  https://github.com/abbbi/virtnbdbackup

Note: As the utility uses features provided only by the qcow disk format, it wont work if you use virtual machines with direct attached ZFS volumes.